# Copy Paste to Guest Ubuntu Server in Virtualbox

Tags: copy-paste

Hi I have windows 7 and virtualbox installed, with Ubuntu server 11.10 as a guest. I would like to copy and paste commands from websites on windows to the ubuntu server command line. The ubuntu server has no GUI installed. Is this possible? I already installed guest additions but it didn't help

Comment: i have found middle clicking (the third mouse button || the scroll button) pastes in cli... also you can install xclip .. if xclip gets the cmd from clipboard then simple  $ eval &#96;xclip -o&#96; will execute your commandComments must be at least 15 characters in length.(click on this box to dismiss)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is how to paste into the Linux Gome Terminal, and in other Apps it is just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
( same reversed for copy using <kbd>C</kbd> and Cut using <kbd>X</kbd> as well )
Hope this helps, took me a long time to get the muscle memory for that one down.

Note, on the Host side, just copy and paste as normal.

Comment: Alternatives: `[Ctrl]+[Ins]` for copy, `[Shift]+[Ins]` for paste.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you telnet or SSH from the host to the guest? That way you don't need to set up the shared clipboard, you're using a remote console, and as long as your local telnet/SSH client supports pasting, you won't have anything to worry about.

(note: I found this searching for a way to paste from an Ubuntu host to an Ubuntu guest, both with GUIs, so I'm suggesting a workaround that would work well for you, but won't for me. If you have a reason to need to paste directly into the local console, then I'm sorry but I'm looking for an answer to the same question.)